# Executing 2 lists of tasks concurrently

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, sms, producer-consumer

Basically I am building an SMS application that reads pending SMS messages from the database and then send them all. There are 2 types of SMS messages; *normal messages* which can be sent at any time, and *urgent messages* which must be sent before any *normal message*. I am using multi-threading within the application.

I want to have 2 queues of *tasks*; one for the normal messages and one for the urgent messages. Then threads in a pool would execute the tasks from the two queues, **taking into account that no SMS mesages from the *normal messages* can be sent unless there are no *urgent messages***.

The implementation would be something as follows:

```
public class SMSApplication
{
    private Queue<SMSTask> normalMessages = new Queue<SMSTask>(); // not necessarily java.util.Queue
    private Queue<SMSTask> urgentMessages = new Queue<SMSTask>();

    // ...

    public void addNormalMessage(SMSTask task)
    {
        normalMessages.add(task);
    }

    public void addUrgentMessage(SMSTask task)
    {
        urgentMessages.add(task);
    }

    public void runApplication()
    {
        /* iterate over the queues, create new threads or select existing ones from a pool, and then execute the tasks */
    }
}
```

What is the best approach to achieve that? Can I accomplish that using [`BlockingQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html)?

Comment: To burn it at both ends, maybe BlockingDeque? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingDeque.html ? The side effect is LIFO for the head; maybe you are fine with that.

Comment: ... oops, wrong URL; meant: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/PriorityBlockingQueue.html

Comment: @full.stack.ex Thanks! I will take a look on [`PriorityBlockingQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/PriorityBlockingQueue.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it with two ConcurrentQueues, one Hi-Pri and one Lo-Pri and a semaphore.

Push the SMS message object onto one of the queues, signal the semaphore.

In your SMS sending thread/s, wait on the semaphore. When a signal is received, check the Hi-Pri queue count first.  If there is an object, get it and send it.  If there is not, get the message from the Lo-Pri queue, (for there is certain to be one), and send it.  Then loop around to wait on the semaphore again.

Comment: +1 Thanks for your answer. Although your answer is correct, but I used [`LinkedBlockingDeque`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingDeque.html) which eliminates the need of having two queues and the need of semaphore :)